# IRobot Scraping tool

Tags: screen-scraping

I am using IRobot scraping tool to obtain some data from website but for some reason it is not comming I think the problem must be of proxy settings can anyone help me to how to change the proxy settings of IRobot scraping tool.

Comment: scrapy tag does not apply to this question

Comment: This appears to be a request for instructions on how to use a piece of software, thus off-topic. Voted to close and move to superuser.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your IE proxy setting, and irobot will use it.

Or you can call SetProxyServer(ip, port, agentname) in robot to change the proxy at run time. If you give the agentname, the proxy will affect only the running robot.

In the software package, there is a sample robot "change_proxy.irb" showing how to randomly pick a proxy from a list of addresses in 'proxy.txt'.  You can copy the task to your robot and call it regularly.